# undefined is not object (evaluating 'RNDeviceInfo.deviceId') - error in react-native-device-info

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am using *react-native-device-info* library, and it works fine for iOS simulator. But for Android I receive an error:

```
undefined is not object (evaluating 'RNDeviceInfo.deviceId')
```

**What can be the problem?**
I installed it like is described in the guide on the library's page (using rnpm).
Then in componentWillMount() I am trying to get the device id:

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
... 
componentWillMount() {
    let clientId = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();
  }
```

Comment: What version of RN are you using?

Comment: "react-native": "^0.27.1"

Comment: And you've followed the other steps on the readme for android? Specifically you've added the code to MainActivity?

Comment: The guide says: "rnpm install react-native-device-info. rnpm will install (--save) this module then linking for react-native, so you don't have to link for each platforms maually as the following." - so it looks like I don't need to do that.

Comment: I looked at the MainActivity - rnpm added those lines automatically.

Comment: Try to check adb log for any errors.

Comment: Weird - I get this error for the iOS simulator...

Comment: Here are others with woes: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/52

Comment: **IOS issue**

For me the problem turned out to be that I had a non-working CocoaPods "installed". After deleting "ios/AuroraTonight.xcworkspace" and "ios/Pods" everything worked in ios. This could point to something being messed up in your lib configs

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `rnpm install react-native-device-info` and instruction from [here](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#installation-android), I had to manually add some lines to the following files:

1. `<YourReactProject>/android/settings.gradle`:

   ```javascript
   rootProject.name = 'YourReactProject'

   include ':app', ':react-native-device-info'
   project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = newFile(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
   ```
2. `<YourReactProject>/android/app/build.gradle`:

   ```javascript
   ...

   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
      compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
      compile project(':react-native-device-info')
   }

   ...
   ```
3. Rebuild by running `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

First check is it added to your package.json or not?
Then link the package with react native using following command

```
react-native link react-native-device-info
```

It manually links the package with react-native.

I am facing this issue in IOS.

Even I link the package it showing the same issue.

open your project in Xcode, 
then under build phases add a binary file of react-native-device-info by clicking on the + button.

Rerun the project, It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly,** make sure that `react-native-device-info` is linked in your project if you are using **react-native version < 0.60.**

**If not linked,** link it using `react-native link react-native-device-info` and then run `react-native run-android` command.

If using **react-native version >= 0.60** skip this link command as auto-linking should work but make sure to run `react-native run-android` command.

and then use it using,

import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

**DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()**

There is a small typo. You are using **DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();** instead of **DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()**

Review in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this package now uses Cocoapods.  Run `react-native link` then check your Podfile for something like this:

```
pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
```

If that's in there, then you just need to install / update your pods.

```
cd ios
pod install
```

or

```
cd ios
pod update
```

Make sure you restart the metro server and re-run `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

use the  [manual installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info) and change

> your project\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\build.gradle'

```
dependencies {
def googlePlayServicesVersion = project.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion') ? project.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION

compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$googlePlayServicesVersion"}
```

in here implementation as a compile